How can i move Flatpak installed apps to another disk?
I'm using Debian 12 Bookworm. I recently started receiving a message from the system saying my root partition (30GB) was almost out of space. Analyzing it, I realized the /var/lib/flatpak/app occupied 11GB. How can I move those installed Flatpak apps to another partition to avoid using my root space?
Thanks for the help!

Short answer: You don't! The problem starts with a very small root partition (for current standards) when using thing like flatpaks or snaps that take a lot more space than the "traditional" packaging. You would need to create a separated /var partition somewhere else, move all the contents of the current one and update /fstab. So, if you were capable of doing all it needs to be done, other than resizing / (or even that), you wouldn't be here asking. Tristis veritas, verum tamen.

Thanks for the comment. But to be very honest with you I did not understand. I'm very new to the Linux world and trying to learn. Do you have a suggestion of content I could read to understand better how can I move the /var to another partition and eventually recreate the /fstab to avoid these problems? Or even uninstalling my flatpak and installing it in another place?

My only suggestion, precisely because you're very new to the Linux world, is to start over, i.e., install Debian with the automated install that creates a single / partition or, if partitioning manually, make sure to give it a lot more than 30GB if you need to install flatpaks and/or snaps. If it wasn't clear from the 1st comments I'm suggestion you do anything but what you'd need to do to move `/var' to its own partition.

That said, if you want to do it, the how is easily searchable on Google or other: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-move-var-directory-to-another-partition Good luck!

I found a really good solution. Solved my problem and reduced the storage in my root folder by 17 GB. The solution was to create a link to the folder containing all the Flatpak apps on another disk:
First move (or copy for backup reasons) the desired location. Like:
mv /var/lib/flatpak /home/apps/flatpak

Then create a link to where the folder was:
ln -s ~/apps/flatpak /var/lib/flatpak

I could use this solution based on a GitHub Issue Comment.
